# sinch sending old deleted messages in onMessageSent

Tags: parse-platform, sinch

Why is sinch sending old deleted messages in onMessageSent of MessageClientListener? These messages were deleted in my Parse backend. I've deleted data of the app on phone, so sinch should n't have this locally. From where is Sinch bringing in all these messages and what should I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi sinch evangelist here.

I am going to try and explain this. Parse and Sinch has nothing to do with each other (we have a tutorial where we show how you can save messages to your own backend like parse) So the fact that you delete from parse has nothing to do with Sinch.

Regarding delivery of messages, we keep all messages for delivery to all devices a user might have for 30 days.

So if you i.e install your app on a new device and login we will ship those messages to that device. And we consider this to be a feature :D

I can agree with you that it might be confusing sometimes, since if you uninstall and app you will get all messages again.

I can see a couple of workarounds for this delete of app and deletions of messages. 
You could either mark messages as deleted in parse and not display to the user, or look at timestamps.