# How to disable sinch chat history?

Tags: sinch, android-sinch-api, sinch-verification

How to disable sinch chat history? It shows when we uninstall and reinstall the app. I think it shows all the chats for the past 30 days. I want to remove them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sinch sending old deleted messages in onMessageSent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129586/sinch-sending-old-deleted-messages-in-onmessagesent)